# How to update angular page without refreshing?

Tags: angular, events

I am using Angular 7 and there is main page.

The main page has lots of buttons and the button has progress bar like this:

[image]

Once working with the component and the component is closed, the button's progress bar should update.

In here, MatDialog is working well for the update function.

However, the new tab one doesn't update.

The other code is exactly same except the closing function.

MatDialog(Working):

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {         
            this.updateProgress(...).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
});
```

New Tab(Not Working):

```
windowRef.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            this.updateProgress(...).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });                
});
```

I found the button's progress bar is update when I click on the other button.
I think any event happened after closing new tab.

In this case how can I make event for main page without refreshing whole page?

Please give me some advise.

I appreciate you in advance and sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: you need manually trigger change detection. inside addEventListener

Comment: When you say "new tab" do you mean a new browser tab? Are you expecting one browser tab to push updates into another browser tab? If so you'll need to facilitate some kind of shared state across all instances of your app. Events fired in one tab will not impact another browser tab. They are two separate instances of angular.

Comment: Yes I mean new browser tab. Once I finished work with new browser tab, the data is updated to server and I checked it. After that I would like to update the main pages progress bar. I need something like event trigger but I have no idea what I use.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing a pub/sub for your app. This will allow you to push events to all active clients and let them know they need to pull an update from the server.

Here is a link to a popular client: https://socket.io